# .NET Core - using entities in a library that have relations to a user entity defined in a project which references the library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on an system where there is a base project (Lets call this project `A`) that is a class library. It contains common entities, controllers, middleware, etc. that I can easily carry forward to future projects. I have a project `B` which depends on the base library `A` in order to inherit its common features. In the future, project C, D, E, F ... will all depend on the base project `A`.

Almost all of the entities in my base library `A`, need to have a relationship to the user entity. For example, my base library will have a `Notification` entity which will need a relation to the `User` for which the notification is for. However the user entity is defined in project `A`, since each project can have different characteristics and fields on the user (all will inherit `IdentityUser`)

The user definition in project `B` might look like this...

```
namespace B
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must max {1} characters long.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        //omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Now consider a class in my base project `A`.

```
namespace A
{
    public class Notification<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //User who this notification is for
        public TUser Owner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've made all of my entities and repositories generic, so I can basically inject whatever user entity I want into the framework from any subsequent project B, C, D, E, F as mentioned earlier.

After hours of trying to get this to work, it all came down to one issue. In my base project `A` suppose I have a controller to view a notification.

```
namespace A
{
    public class NotificationController<TUser> : BaseController
    {
        private readonly INotificationRepository<TUser> _notificationRepository;
        public NotificationController(INotificationRepository<TUser> notificationRepository)
        {
            _notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllNotifications()
        {
            var notifications = await _notificationRepository.GetNotificationsAsync();
            return Json(notifications);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, in my project `B`, I could register the controller defined in the library `A`, using something like this:

```
 services.AddMvc()
             ...
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(A.NotificationController).Assembly);
```

However, that doesn't seem to work with a generic controller. Ideally, I would do something like this

```
services.AddMvc()
             ...
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(A.NotificationController<User>).Assembly); //Where User is the User defined in project B
```

This does not work and the controllers actions all are error 404. I'm forced do do this another way. I have to create a dummy controller in project B, which acts as a wrapper:

```
namespace B
{
    public class NotificationController : A.NotificationController<User>
    {
        public NotificationController(INotificationRepository<User> notificationRepository)
            : base(notificationRepository)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Having this controller in project `B` means its picked up by MVCCore, and can properly fill in the generics for the Controller and the repository. Using this approach everything compiles and runs perfectly, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, or I'm doing everything wrong.

The way I've done things seems convoluted to me, but its also been years since I've done any major work using a statically typed language so maybe there isn't a better way.

I felt this question was most appropriate here but if this type of question is not fit for stackoverflow, please suggest a more appropriate community (codereview or softwareengineering).

Comment: It just tells your that your project architecture is flawed and the models all belong to the same DbContext (assuming you use Entity Framework) and hence in the same assembly.

Comment: P.S. Generic Controllers are **not detected** by ASP.NET Core routning conventions when doing routing. This is **by design** though. `[Route]` annotation may work though. As for The `AddApplicationPart`, you can use  `.AddApplicationPart(typeof(A.NotificationController<>).Assembly);` without the type name (notice the `<>` though) to get

Comment: @Tseng All of my models are in the same db context. The base class models entities that are used in the base project, and project "B", has a DbContext which inherits the BaseDbContext in project "A". Its all in the same dbcontext, it just happens to be inheriting some thing from the base project. Is that bad design?